# Which RAM slot is being used when I run a program in Windows?

Tags: windows, memory

Suppose that I have two ram slots and 1GB at each. I wonder what is the priority order for RAM slots in Windows. When I run a program, does Windows full a RAM slot and then use the second one or use them both together?

Comment: They are used equally.  Windows uses all available memory as needed.

Comment: In the case of RAM, the point of congestion is the bus to the CPU, so by using both sticks simultaneously the CPU spends less time waiting for the bus to be idle, when performing parallel operations.

Comment: The correct answer depends on whether your system is using single-channel or dual-channel memory access.  You would also need to determine where the virtual memory that your program uses is mapped to in physical memory.  But there is no *"priority"* to memory modules as you ask.